# MVC5 + Angular JS folder structure

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to angular and trying to learn best practises. what is the best practice for a folder structure for an ASP.NET MVC5 AngularJS application.

```
MVC5 default structure
- Controllers Folder
- Models Folder
- Views Folder ---> Action Name Folder
```

(now to bring in Angular)In the **scripts folder** in the project would we then have:

```
controller folder
Module folder
Views Folder etc
```

Your help will be truly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating AngularJs app first time then follow simple steps.

1. Create one **index.JSP** file where you should run your app using `ng-app` directive and add all scripts and files.
2. create one Js file `app.js`.
   add all module name in **app.js** and run your js using .run method.
3. maintain `services, controllers and filters, directives, templates`   seperately in different folders and in different files.
   And dont forget to add module name in **app.js** and add path in **index.jsp**
4. In your `services` files write only **sharing business logic**.
   All other business logic related to particular file write it in controller.
   Here your are maintaining ajax calls so dont meshup it with controllers.

**Service**

```
.factory('angularService', function () {
  return {
    // Write business logic
  }
})
```

5. Declare `$starteProvider` and define `.states` in your controller.

**For ex.**

```
$stateProvider.state('xyz_state', function () {
   // add url,
   // templateUrl,
   // controller
})
.controller('myFirstController', function () {
   // Add your business logic
   // scope variables
});
```

6. Maintain view pages separately.
7. Maintain `Directives` and `Filters` separately.

View simply renders your model and you can control both **model** and **view** using controller and services.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. I'll be calling mvc controller actions using $http.get so from what i understanding You're saying i should place all this logic in the services? Are there any examples of how to manage multiple $http.gets realting to different controllers